# Как достать обложку альбома файла мр3?

Tags: java, android

Конкретной инфы нет, где и с какого байта искать обложку. Может у кого есть соображения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью класса [MediaMetadataRetriever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) :

```
        MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        mmr.setDataSource("/path/to/file.mp3");
        byte[] imageBytes = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
        mmr.release();
        if (imageBytes != null) {
            // decode to Bitmap
            // or save to file
            // etc.
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Хм наксколько знаю обложка хранится в скрытом файле jpg

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349581/mp3-cover-art-tagging-in-c-sharp вот кое что из этого

Comment: http://ru.wikihow.com/%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8--MP3-%D0%BD%D0%B0-Windows-7

Comment: нужно достать это, что бы то ни было!)